# I need to kill the sprite

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner coder and i am learning my ways in python and i am coding a game where you catch apples in a basket and get score but i have come across a problem. i do not know how to kill my sprites and i really need to do that so i can catch the apples in the basket and not get more than one score. Can anyone please help me with killing the apple sprite?

```
import pygame
import random


class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y, player_rect):
        self.screen = screen
        self.apple_image = pygame.image.load("../assets/apple.png")
        self.apple_rect = self.apple_image.get_rect()
        self.player_rect = player_rect
        Score = 0


        pygame.draw.rect(self.apple_image, red, pygame.Rect(self.apple_rect),  2)

        self.apple_rect.x = x
        self.apple_rect.x = y


   

    def update(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.apple_image, (self.apple_rect.x, self.apple_rect.y))
        self.apple_rect.y += 5








    
    



pygame.init()
game_width = 1275
game_height = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width, game_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
background_image = pygame.image.load("../assets/sky.png")

self_x = 375
self_y = 600

apple_x = random.randint(0, game_width)
apple_y = random.randint(0, 100)


apple_spawn_timer_max = 150
apple_spawn_timer = 0

red = (255, 0, 0)

apple = False
Score = 0






player_image = pygame.image.load("../assets/basket.png")

player_rect = player_image.get_rect()



while running:
    # Makes the game stop if the player clicks the X or presses esc
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

    #draw background
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(player_image, (self_x, self_y))
    pygame.draw.rect(player_image, red, pygame.Rect(player_rect),  2)




    

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #gets list of booleans of keys on keyboard being pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        self_x+=10
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        self_x-=10

    if self_x > 1155:
        self_x = 1155

    if self_x < -20:
        self_x = -20

    apple_spawn_timer -= 1
    if apple_spawn_timer <= 0:
        apple_x = random.randint(0, game_width)
        apple_y = random.randint(0, 50) 
        A = Apple(screen, apple_x, apple_y, player_rect)
        apple = True
        apple_spawn_timer = apple_spawn_timer_max
           

    if apple == True:
        A.update()

        player_rect.x = self_x
        player_rect.y = self_y

        if A.apple_rect.colliderect(player_rect):
            Score += 1




    print(Score)







    


    



    pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(50)
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill your sprites, use `self.kill()` inside the Apple class
Like for example you could make a function inside the Apple class like this:

```
def destroy(self):
    self.kill()
```

or:

```
def update(self):
    # ...
    if self.apple_rect.x > 1000:
        self.kill()
```

I haven't tested this but it could maybe work if you destroy the instance of the class like this

```
apple = Apple()
apple.kill()
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have an apple variable (apple = False/True) and I have tried the function solution. It sorta speeds them up when they collide with the basket rect.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if A.apple_rect.colliderect(player_rect):
   Score += 1
   # implement something here to reset your A object
   # If you really want to delete it entirely you can use the del keyword
   del A
   # But maybe if you have to respawn your object after that, 
   # just change the position to get out of this collision, 
   # or use your apple=False flag.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have no idea how i didnt think of resseting the apple to False :D